# .htaccess rewrite rule for removing .php extension with exception of wp login and wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
# Remove filename extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# This will remove the .php extension if it is not a directory, the file does not exist and it's not a WordPress specific admin page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-(content|admin|includes)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.2.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code works fine by removing `.php` extension of URLs indexed already by Google and redirecting them to new ones. But `.php` extension of `wp-login`, and other `wp-admin` URLs also get removed.

So I would like to add an exception to  URLs `/wp-login.php` or under `wp-admin` directory.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? No PHP files under `wp-includes` or `wp-admin` should get indexed, and anything else gets routed via permalinks

Comment: Hi Muneeb, welcome to [wordpress.se]. Your question may need editing to get the best answers. For example what your goal is, (you have already added what you have done and the result). There may be an easier way to get what you want. As a quick guide, pretend you are talking to a busy colleague and have to tell them everything they absolutely need to give you a clear answer before they rush away. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: The old site was based on php and there are lot of pages which are indexed, since we are keeping same urls in new wp sites but without .php extension at the end... the above mention code also remove .php from admin pages too.

Comment: I found an exact answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762607/regex-to-match-all-php-file-extensions-in-url-except-for-if-found-in-the-admin/52762758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The old site was based on php and there are lot of pages which are indexed, since we are keeping same urls in new wp sites but without .php extension at the end...

Assuming your "old site" `.php` documents no longer exist (they shouldn't) then your current rule block to remove the `.php` extension would seem to be far more complex than it needs to be (and/or incorrect). (See below.)

> the above mention code also remove .php from admin pages too.

Ok, something a bit odd here... Your existing rule block already excludes any URL that *contains* `/wp-admin/` - so this should already exclude your admin pages. To also exclude `wp-login.php` you could simply modify this same condition, although this would seem to be unnecessary (see below). `wp-login.php` is not the only exception you need to make and adding many exceptions in this way quickly becomes impractical.

A quick assessment of your current rule block...

> ```
> 1. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-(content|admin|includes)/ [NC]
> 2. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> 3. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
> 4. RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
> 5. RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
> ```

1. As noted above, this already excludes any URL that *contains* `/wp-content/`, `/wp-admin/` or `/wp-includes/`. However, assuming none of your old site URLs start with `wp-` then why not simply exclude any URL that starts `/wp-` - which naturally includes `wp-login.php`, `/wp-admin`, etc. There are potentially more than just `wp-login` and `wp-admin` URLs that need to be excluded here.
2. Why do you need to check that the request does not map to a filesystem directory? Do you have directories that also end in `.php`?! Filesystem checks are relatively expensive and this condition looks superfluous.
3. This check is not doing what (I think) you think it's doing. The preceding comment states "the file does not exist" - that's not what this condition does. If it did then you probably would not be asking your question. No part of this code checks that "the file does not exist", which is really your main problem. If you request `/foo.php` then this condition checks that `/foo.php.php` does not exist (which I'm sure it doesn't), or if you request `/foo/bar/baz.php` (where `/foo/bar` does not exist as a physical directory) then it checks that `/foo.php` does not exist - probably not the intention.
4. The purpose of the check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable is to avoid a redirect loop - however, it can be simplified (the fragment identifier is never passed to the server, so `#` is never matched). If your old URLs never contain a query string then it can be simplified further. But note that if your old URLs did/do contain a query string, then this will currently be passed onto the new target URL - is this the intention?
5. This redirect only works because of the `RewriteBase` directive that is set later in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. Ideally, you would include the slash prefix on the *substitution* or include the canonical protocol + hostname (an absolute URL) and avoid a potential second redirect later.

#### Solution

Bringing the above points together, try something like the following instead (there is no need for the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^GET /.+\.php(\?\S*)? HTTP/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$)(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Surrounding the *CondPattern* in quotes (ie. `"`..`"`) avoids the need to escape spaces in the regex.

`\S` is a shorthand negated character class that matches any non-whitespace character. Similar to `[^\ ]` as you had initially.

`(?!index\.php$)` - This *negative lookahead assertion* in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* ensures we don't try to process the request after it has been rewritten to `index.php` by the WP front-controller.

The filesystem check (really just a failsafe) is the last condition since this is the most "expensive", so it's only processed when the other conditions (and `RewriteRule` *pattern*) are successful.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: thanks for giving a detailed explanation.